# No cpu % in Process table in system monitor

Tags: process

The column is there but I have never seen any numbers there in my fedora 24 distro. Why?

In gkrellm there are two cores out of 12 running at 100%, other cores running at approx 2-30%.

I used debian unstable before and there I usually saw some processes now and then showing numbers in the cpu % column. Never ever seen any numbers there in fedora... The pulldown meny at right says "All Processes".

In System load tab, looking at CPU history I would say avarage is currently at about 10%, excluding the two cores at 100%.

So how can I find out wich processes are using two cores at 100% ?
Htop shows by graphs two cores running at 100% but never ever any numbers in the cpu% column...